# How can I turn on automatic updates of applications or at least notifications on new app updates?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, notifications, android-12, application-autoupdate

I have a Nokia G22 phone with Android 12. I would like to have automatic updating working, or at least to be notified on new app updates in Google Play Store. In Applications > Google Play Store I have "Updates available" notifications turned on. I even have automatic updates of apps turned on through wi-fi. I am connected to wi-fi most of my daily phone use. Currently I need to check and run the updates manually in Google Play Store > tap to my profile > Manage applications and devices > Updates Available, and each time I check it, I see tens of updates available. How can I automate this? What else should I check to be turned on?

Comment: Play Store only does automatic updates on a very specific condition listed in [Manage app updates](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9350374), particularly when the device is charging and not being used.

Comment: The specific condition (connected to wi-fi & charging & phone not used & apps not running) is met every day.

Comment: You can try clearing the cache of Play store first and if that doesn't help clear data too followed by a reboot. You might need to do some extra things like setting up cards in your wallet etc if you delete data but nothing catastrophic